# Filter objects based on th current user django model admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Hello I am trying to filter objects in model inline admin based on a field in `Profile` models I have created with a OneToOneField with `User` the profile model has a field  branch
so I want to filter objects based on the logged-in user with respect to their branch

```
class ProductDetailInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    readonly_fields = ('created_date', 'generated_url')
    model = ProductDetail
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "product":
            kwargs["queryset"] = ProductDetail.objects.filter(
                product=request.user.profile.branch_id)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

the product foreignkey still returns everything without filtering out the branch. How do I accomplish the filtering?

Comment: can you post other portion of the code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs): if db_field.name == "product": kwargs["queryset"] = ProductDetail.objects.filter( product=request.user.profile.branch_id) return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

My problem was I added product to autocomplete field and its returned all the query ignoring the filter.